# How to perform async opeartion in antd Modal component?

Tags: reactjs, antd

```
import {Button, Modal} from 'antd';

const confirm = Modal.confirm;

class MeetupDetail extends Component {
    showDeleteConfirm() {
    confirm({
      title: 'Are you sure delete this meetup?',
      okText: 'Yes',
      okType: 'danger',
      cancelText: 'No',
      onOk() {
        this.onDelete();
      },
      onCancel() {
        console.log('Cancel');
      },
    });
  }

onDelete() {
    let meetupId = this.state.details.id;
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/api/meetups/${meetupId}`)
      .then(response => {
        this.props.history.push('/');
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

    render(){
        return(
  <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between', paddingTop: '20px' }}>
          <Button type="primary" icon="edit">Edit</Button>
          <Button onClick={this.showDeleteConfirm.bind(this)} type="danger" icon="delete">Delete</Button>
        </div>
        ) 
    }
}
```

Passing this.onDelete.bind(this) as an Onclick for the Button delete will work.
But i want to show a modal before deleting the item and i used Modal component of antd ui framework. After showing a model when i choose Yes option it raises an error, TypeError: Cannot read property 'onDelete' of undefined

Comment: You are losing scope when you bind your `onDelete` function in the render method. Move your `this.showDeleteConfirm.bind(this)` into the constructor and you should be good.

Comment: I did it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Where is your Modal code? Can you post your updated code with the modal?

Comment: Updated @Chase DeAnda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
confirm({
  ...
  onOk: () => {
    this.onDelete();
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it async you could do this,

```js
const confirm = () => {
    Modal.confirm({
      ......
      onOk: async () => {
        await onDelete();
      },
});
```

This call the onDelete method async inside the ok button